# What does 'Staff Pick' on a job listing signify?

Tags: support, stack-overflow-jobs

Today I noticed this in jobs listings, which I don't think I've seen before:

[image: snip of a job listing showing one job tagged with Staff Pick 2018]

Clicking through shows this on the job page itself:

[image: Short sentence saying something about what Staff Pick is, but not much]

What is this? Which Staff have Picked this, and on what basis? Is the *job* a staff pick, or the *company*? There's nothing about this on the blog.

Comment: It's that we (internally) voted their company pages and those are the winners. We only looked at their company pages (not their jobs). I've pinged somebody with more details to properly answer this one, but in the meantime [check our this blog post](https://www.stackoverflowbusiness.com/blog/staff-picks-10-company-pages-we-love) we wrote on the employer facing blog.

Comment: Maybe we should display a link to that blog post next to the "staff pick" badge?

Comment: Or maybe there's just better wording than "Staff Pick", since it has to do with the employer and not the specific job posting? Something like "Featured Employer" or similar? As written, it's pretty unclear as to even what is being identified as the "Staff Pick".

Comment: Or just remove it because it appears to hold no actual meaningful value to page visitors. It's just noise that doesn't tell anyone anything. I guess the intent is to reward companies that produce decent online shop fronts, and thereby encourage others to do better - which is a noble goal but again this badge has no actual direct value to readers here.

Comment: Does "staff pick" go to the company that pays the most by any chance? I can see the sales person now, "sure place x amount of job ads and we'll make you a staff pick, that sounds cool right?!".

Comment: Isn't that what community voting is for? To validate quality? I don't use the job board but... wait, can we not vote on job postings?

Comment: @Liam I'm one of the devs who voted and can assure you that this was absolutely not the case. Adding an answer below to elaborate a bit.

Comment: I want to be able to vote and comment on job postings.

Comment: @Tezra - its been asked for and declined.  SO is too much against downvoting or reviewing companies...which makes Indeed a better job placement board.

Answer (score -10, accepted):

The Staff Pick applies to the Company Page, not the job listing.

We asked companies to update their Company Pages in September so that they may be considered for "Staff Pick."

The criteria we used was, first and foremost, completeness (did the employer complete all the fields?), supplemented by qualitative evaluation by developers and designers that work at Stack Overflow on how successful the content is in convincing a prospective candidate to consider the company as an employer.

This is part of our continuing efforts to improve the quality of Company Pages on our site and help Stack Overflow users discover companies they might not have known about.

Agree with you that the explainer copy on the badge could be clearer. We will update it to clarify that the Company Pages were chosen by Stack Overflow's own developers and add a link to the blog post to provide context. Thanks for your feedback!

Comment: I'm inclined to push back on this, though - what's the basis for thinking that completeness of a profile and the degree to which marketing copy is convincing is good grounds on which to designate an employer as worthy of extra consideration? Has any time been spent validating that these are actually higher quality employers than average? It seems like these employers are being recommended to Stack Overflow's users based on metrics which are disproportionately relevant to the health of the Stack Overflow Jobs product, not necessarily to applicant outcomes.

Comment: The "Staff Pick" label indicates that this is a stamp of approval, not a "dotted all the I's and crossed all the T's" type of verification. If you intend to keep this, in addition to making sure there is a link to the blog post, I would seriously consider rewording the text on that label, unless you *actually* wanted it to be a stamp of approval, but you need different mechanisms in place to have that so I bet that is not the case.

Comment: Some of my best jobs were in small companies that simply will not have the ressources to do all that verify. Does that mean they were bad environments? Because that is kinda what this gives as a feeling...

Comment: Sorry this doesn't sound right at all. I once interviewed at a place that had all the bells and whistles - gaming, food, a nice looking office - they could not keep a person there longer than 6 months. So they would of been a "staff pick". Plain and simple - get rid of it ASAP.  You're going to alienate other customers and mislead programmers.

Answer (score 49):

This is just **subjective noise**. It does not add any useful information to the job posting and should be removed. Why do I(we) care what a handful of people (mostly based in New York) think about a company?

Especially when this decision seems to be mostly based on [looking at the pretty pictures](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/375236/542251) provided by said company.

Should I base my career decision on a companies spend in recruitment marketing? I'm sure SO jobs would like me to do this, mainly because they make money from recruitment marketing.

Seriously what a load of absolute trite hokum.

Comment: Staff Pick === Company marketing/recruiting agents having the necessary skill (fill in textboxes and use buzzwords) to make their company profile page look appealing to the uninformed consumer. Got it!

Comment: Max lists some good metrics (blog posts, open source projects) that can be extra fields the company themselves can fill in. For some people these are important (like quite working conditions). Or, we could just leave good enough alone and not add unnecessary fields, either works for me

Answer (score 5):

Seems like it'd be unnecessarily divisive among employers.

Presumably SO wants every employer to spend money with them for advertisements. What is a prospective employer going to think if they'll automatically be classed as "second class" (not excplicitly recommended) because of some very subjective criteria of staff opinion. I'd revisit my decision to advertise with SO if that was a possibility and I was an employer.

Answer (score -10):

I'm one of the SO devs who voted. If it helps, here's what I was looking for while reviewing a fairly large set of company pages:

- Companies would generally stand out to me if they made me feel that they were truly making an effort to be an appealing place to work *for developers*.
- An interesting "tech stack" section with links to open source projects and engineering blogs would be a huge plus to me. Just a bag of tags with no additional context- not so much.
- In the "gallery" section, I'd mainly look out for a dev-friendly office environment (low noise, little distractions; ideally single offices).

Interestingly, our team compared notes after voting and we found that in some regards, we had quite different priorities. For some of us, technologies came first; others focused more on the product; and others would primarily be interested in the team they'd be working with.

Now, does a great company page *guarantee* that a company is a great place to work and the right fit for *you*? Of course not. The "Staff Pick" badge is just an additional signal we provide for your consideration. I will say though that some companies try *a lot* harder than others and there were quite noticeable difference between those who made the staff pick list and those who didn't.

Comment: *The "Staff Pick" badge is just an additional signal we provide for your consideration.* Does it really need to exist though? It could be read as some form of SO "endorsement" (intended or not)...

Comment: ... and were I advertising a role that I've paid for on the site and I see my listing come up next to something that'd been "judged" better so I'm going to potentially get less applications because of it - I'd probably not be overly impressed.

Comment: I'm not sure why this is downvoted so much as it clearly explains what the badge stands for (and what not).

Comment: @MártonMolnár sadly votes seem to work different on Meta. They seem more correlated to opinion than correctness. :-/

Comment: @stealththeninja its not a bug its a feature. Meta is the place where we discuss to see how we want SO to be, therefore we need a system to show agreement/disagreement.

Comment: @AnderBiguri understood. In cases where users simply explain how something currently works, it can be a flogging.

Comment: I don't mind a good flogging in the morning! Coffee's overrated anyways.

Comment: Sorry this doesn't sound right at all. I once interviewed at a place that had all the bells and whistles - gaming, food, a nice looking office - they could not keep a person there longer than 6 months. So they would of been a "staff pick". Plain and simple - get rid of it ASAP.  You're going to alienate other customers and mislead programmers.

Comment: @stealththeninja Meta questions also have a tendency to morph over time, or be reinterpreted -- this question only explicitly asks "what does it mean", but it also implicitly asks "is this really worth it".

Comment: +1 for explaining what it's for, as this is the answer to the question, but -2 cause it feels very unwarranted. I'd much rather users be able to upvote + downvote jobs. The problem with only allowing this upvoting, is that 4 people in your office may have agreed with it and 20 actual applicants may have disagreed with it, but we don't see the opinions of those people.

Comment: Can the staff also vote on the worst company pages? I'm interested in companies that are too small and/or busy to devote a lot of time to their recruiting pitches here.